# Find most called methods using Perfview

Tags: c#, profiling, perfview

Is there a way to find the method calls count using Perfview tool (i.e info on how many times each method was called during the profiling period)?

I remember seeing similar functionality in JetBrains' DotTrace, but am not sure if it exists in Perfview - I suspect maybe becuase Perfview always does sampling, it can't really track number of method calls with any accuracy?

Comment: you have to raise own events when you launch an method and later you can count the amount of the events

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look into it!